# How can we print out total number of posts filtered by post type and category?

Tags: posts, terms

I'm using this code that will print out the ID for current post's terms.

```
foreach((get_the_terms($post->ID, 'project_category')) as $term) { 
echo $term->term_id. '';
}
```

Now i want to put this term id in this code.

```
$term = get_term( '7', 'category' ); 
$count = $term->count;
echo $count;
```

This code will print '2' as there are two posts in a category having term id 7. I want to replace '7' with the output from the upper code.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understood, you want to run a loop and print the count for every term of your post. You can do so by this code:

```
foreach((get_the_terms($post->ID, 'project_category')) as $term) { 
    $term_object = get_term( $term->term_id, 'category' );
    echo $term_object->count;
}
```

Which will do what you asked for.

Comment: I want to print total number of posts in a particular category.